# Is there a way to debug play2 app on heroku?

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to find a way  to debug my play2 app on heroku.
I would like to connect my debuger (from idea) to it that I can check what's going on.
I tried to launch my app in debug mode but I don't know how to do this. Maybe through the Procfile ?

I also tried to connect myself on the server with `heroku run bash` and find the play command to launch my app with `play debug run` but I wasn't able to do so. Is that possible ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: I found and tried this : http://mikeslinn.blogspot.fr/2012/09/debugging-jvm-programs-on-heroku.html but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't as the port won't be available to connect.

Your only chance is to add extensive debug logging and enable `DEBUG`level on `application.conf`so you see what's going on.

Comment: Ok, too bad. I will follow your advice. Thank you.